# L1D cache miss behaviour and Linux scheduling

Tags: linux, caching, x86, intel, cpu-cache

I have a very specific question regarding some interesting behaviour I observed some performing experiments with L1D cache miss rates for certain programs.

Basically, I tried to find out how high the L1D load miss rate of a Tomcat9 server is when it's running alone on an isolated core. Additionally, I wanted to compare this value to the miss rate when I invalidate the L1D cache using the IA32_FLUSH_CMD msr upon each context switch.

As you would expect, the miss rate is higher when I invalidate the cache.

Now here comes the interesing part: I tried the same thing running both my tomcat server and additionally an apache2 web server. The result was that the miss rate for the tomcat server is actually HIGHER than when I invalidate the cache on each context switch, which I don't really understand. I would expect it to be at most as high as the miss rate measure with invalidating the cache, because, while the web server may evict some (maybe even all) of the lines of the tomcat server, it should most likely keep some aswell. And even if it evicted all of the lines, I'd expect that to give me a similar miss rate as when I invalidate the cache.

Some important information about the system:

1. SMT is disabled, so no cache interference from other CPUs
2. For the tests I'm running benchmarks to send continuous requests to both servers.
3. i7-7700k (32kb l1d cache)
4. Ubuntu Server 20.04, Kernel v5.13

If you have any idea about why this happens, I'd really appreciate the input.

Thank you!

Comment: Running two things at once will cause many more context switches.  Is your experiment controlling for the number of context switches?  e.g. by forcing them to happen.  (Just counting them and looking at misses / switch would be something, but you'd expect to be much lower with infrequent context switches, as you'd spend a lot of time in the cache-hot steady state.  So it's not easy to just "control" for it with different frequencies of context switches).  Note that entering the kernel for a system call or timer interrupt isn't a context switch, `current` is still the same user-space task.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for your answer! I also recorded the runtime of each of the threads because I suspected a decrease as well, and they don't seem to change. Also, kernel managed interrupts are disabled for the test core. I will have a look at misses per switch, maybe that can give me a hint.

Comment: `perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,instructions` plus any other `-e` events like `L1-dcache-load-misses` you want to add will count actual context switches.  `--all-user` will count only user-space events, or `L1-dcache-load-misses:u` will count user-space events only for that one event, so you're only seeing misses from Tomcat, not from the kernel before returning to user-space.  Or `mem_load_retired.l1_miss` to use a uarch-specific event name.

Comment: I will look at the events you suggested to see if I can spot something. Thanks, for now, will come back to this when I have the results! :)

Comment: As a sidenote, I'm using a custom kernel to log the data from the context_switch routine

Comment: @PeterCordes I looked at instructions per schedule as well as all_loads per schedule and found that when the web server is also running, some tomcat threads actually seem to do more work than when it's running alone. I made a [histogram](https://imgur.com/ek1hXz6) comparing user and kernel instructions / sched between the two workloads and it seems that the app_web workload - on average - has slightly fewer instructions in the kernel, but significantly more in userspace. I also made a [plot](https://imgur.com/m2eBwJm) comparing individual threads. Here especially "http-nio-8080-A" has a much

Comment: higher instruction rate in userspace. I'm not sure why that is, but it's probably something that I won't be able to control. Thanks, either way. I will try to find a way around that problem in my experiments!

Comment: PS.: http-nio-8080-B is only scheduled a few times. I also looked at pagefaults, no change there. The threads in the bar char (A, C, e) are the ones scheduled most often, but there are others running as well.